# Month list not showing in Vue Datepicker

Tags: javascript, css, datepicker, vuejs3

I am using Vue Date picker in my Vue3 application. While clicking the month, the month list is not appearing.

When I checked the docs, there are no such configurations to enable/disable it. The list is showing when i clicked the examples provided in the docs. I have pasted the same in my application, but not working

Comment: Wecome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately your question doesn't really provide us with a lot to go on. Please provide us with at least a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can help you solve your problem.

Comment: you'll need to specify which "vue date picker" you're using, since there are several - you've probably done something wrong - have you checked the browser *developer* tools console for any errors?

Comment: Yes I have checked. No errors in the console. I am using "@vuepic/vue-datepicker": "^6.1.0"